# Querying Typescript array collection based on key

Tags: javascript, linq, collections, typescript

I am new to Typescript. I have an Array of type  in typescript.Basically containing the collection elements as

```
"ID": "669a8156-528c-43ba-8ed0-d07874534d1c",
"Name": "Temple",
"DeviceCount": "0",
"SiteCount": "0"
```

---

```
"ID": "5965ee85-2300-4c95-8743-b626f744082f",
"Name": "Building",
"DeviceCount": "2",
"SiteCount": "3"
```

---

..so on

How do I query the **Name** property from the collection if I have the **ID**

i.e., something similar to LINQ type of expression

```
var result = array.Where(item => item.ID == ID);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the JavaScript `Array#filter` method for this, which returns an array of matches, very similar to your LINQ code:

```
array.filter(item => item.ID === ID)[0].name;
```

You could also use `Array#find`, but that doesn't have very good browser support, so you might need a polyfill for Opera and Internet Explorer:

```
array.find(item => item.ID === ID).name;
```

Read documentation about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Is the TypeScript way of representation the sameway as JS

Comment: Yes, this code will work in TypeScript and in modern JavaScript, except that TypeScript compiles the arrow function `x => y` for you, which otherwise wouldn't be supported in Safari and some other browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work for me. Although the collection had the specific entry.