# Querying Typescript array collection based on key in an Angular HTML component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've just started with Angular 2 and TypeScript.

I want to show data in a table. One of the values I want to show is an Id (a key) of another table. Instead of showing that Id I want to show its name.

Searching I have found how to do it in TypeScript in this SO question: [Querying Typescript array collection based on key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37982220/querying-typescript-array-collection-based-on-key).

I have copied the first answer and add it to my html component:

```
<div class="col-md-1">{{codeTypes.find(c => c.codeTypeId == level.codeType)[0].name}}</div>
```

But I get a syntax error with `{{`. If I remove `{{` and `}}` I only see in the html this:

```
codeTypes.find(c => c.codeTypeId == level.codeType)[0].name
```

`codeTypes` is a public property in the TS class:

```
public codeTypes: ICodeType[];
```

And `ICodeType` is declared as:

```
export interface ICodeType {
    codeTypeId: number;
    name: string;
}
```

I want to query `codeTypes` array to search the one with the same `codeTypeId` I have and show its `name` instead. How can I do it inside a HTML component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do the same in Angular template syntax, as it is not equivalent to javascript, but rather a subset of it; as a matter of fact, lambdas are not allowed as they may collide with interpolation syntax ({} - curly braces). Try using a `Pipe` or invoking a method from your Component's class to do the querying instead of doing it inside the template. I would striongly suggest Pipes

Using a method:

```
queryArray() {
   return this.codeTypes.find(c => c.codeTypeId == this.level.codeType)[0].name
}
```

In the html:

```
<div class="col-md-1">{{ queryArray() }}</div>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I had no thought about using a method to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement this using pipes.

Html:

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
 <tr>
  <th>District</th>
 </tr>
 <tr *ngFor="let item of records | slice:0:5 | category: searchText">
  <td>{{item.DistrictName}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" class="form-control"
placeholder="Search By Id" />
```

category.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'category' })

export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(categories: any, searchText: any): any {
    if(searchText == null) return categories;

    return categories.filter(
      function(category){
       return category.id.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
      }
    )
  }
}
```

include the pipe in typescript file

```
import {CategoryPipe} from './category.pipe';


and then
export class CheckListComponent implements OnInit {
records: Array<any>;
this.records= [
{ DistrictName: "Ariyalur", id: "1" },
{ DistrictName: "Chennai", id: "2" },
{ DistrictName: "Coimbatore", id: "3" },
{ DistrictName: "Cuddalore",  id: "4" },
{ DistrictName: "Dharmapuri", id: "5" },
{ DistrictName: "Dindigul", id: "6" },
{ DistrictName: "Erode", id: "7" },
];
```

and in app.module.ts have to declare that

```
import {CategoryPipe} from './category.pipe';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
CategoryPipe
],
```

Comment: i would strongly suggest pipes